# Good Old Suffix Vector

Tags: code-challenge

Inspired by an old manual...

#### The challenge

I define the *a*<sup>th</sup> suffix vector of *b* as the boolean list of length *a* with *b* trailing truthy values.

Write a program or function that, given *a* and *b* by any means, returns the *a*<sup>th</sup> suffix vector of *b* by any means.

Now this may seem trivial, but here is the catch: Your score is the byte count plus the earliest year your solution would have worked.

#### Rules

All standard rules apply, except that languages and language versions that were released after this challenge, may also be used.

Output using whatever representation of boolean values that your language uses, e.g. `1`/`0`, `True`/`False`, `TRUE`/`FALSE`, `"True"`/`"False"`, etc.

Output using whatever representation of lists that your language uses, e.g. `0 0 1`, `[False,False,True]`, `(FALSE;FALSE;TRUE)`, `{"False","False","True"}`, etc.

You may assume that *a* ≥ *b* is always true and that they are of an appropriate data type.

#### Test cases

Given *a* = 7 and *b* = 3, return `0 0 0 0 1 1 1`

Given *a* = 4 and *b* = 4, return `[True,True,True,True]`

Given *a* = 2 and *b* = 0, return `(FALSE;FALSE)`

Given *a* = 0 and *b* = 0, return `{}`

#### Example solution and scoring

I might want to submit the solution `{⌽⍺↑⍵⍴1}` using Dyalog APL. That would be a bytecount of 8. This is a dynamic function, which works from version 8.1 of Dyalog APL, released in 1998, so my total score is 2006. My submitted answer should look something like:

```
# Dyalog APL 8.1, 1998 + 8 = 2006
    {⌽⍺↑⍵⍴1}

Optional explanation...
Recommended: Link to documentation showing when the features you used were released.
```

Lowest score wins!

Comment: I'm deeply concerned about the verifiability of the answers.

Comment: @Dennis Same. For example I am fairly confident that my answer would have worked on the first Prolog interpreters but I actually can't easily check it.

Comment: @Dennis I understand you concern. However, 1) the answers will mostly be very simple, and thus could be verified by hand – not requiring an actual running system, and 2) some users have taken to linking to documentation of their claim.

Comment: I'm not so sure "verified by hand" is necessarily going to work for some answers - the past is a foreign place, and sometimes initial versions of things can lack things that feels commonplace today...

Comment: @Sp3000 Maybe, but this is all for fun anyway, and with 8 answers and 9 upvotes in 1.5h, I think this challenge is fun enough accept that someone might cheat. Maybe some extra research on the eventual winner...

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ If a release is dated on 31 December, that may be interpreted as the following year depending on locale (see drolex's comment to my answer). Can Github date be used as the official date (whatever  locale the Github server is using)? Should I add `1` to the score just in case?

Comment: SMP, 1983+94=2077:`{[0]:{[0]:{},[2]:"(FALSE;FALSE)"},[3]:{[7]:"0 0 0 0 1 1 1"},[4]:{[4]:"[True,True,True,True]"}}` Moral of the story: don't mix output formats.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy What?

Comment: I'd suggest using one array format for the test cases.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy The idea was to show that any of those formats are valid. I think the cases are few and simple enough that ease of copy-paste'ing isn't an issue.

Comment: There's an answer that displays the *string* `{}` for the empty list. However, in TI-BASIC, `{}` doesn't represent anything; it throws an error when evaluated. Is this valid?

Comment: Hang on, working on an answer using http://history-computer.com/Babbage/NextDifferentialEngines/Scheutz.html. `:-)`

Comment: [Things to avoid when writing challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8195/46231).

Comment: This is an old challenge, but it isn't explicitly stated: is a lower score better?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### APL\360, 1968 + 3 bytes = 1971

```
⎕⍵⎕
```

A builtin from the [tutorial](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APL360TerminalSystem.htm) @NBZ linked to. I don't know why @NBZ said it would score 1970, because APL\360 wasn't implemented until 1968, and earlier APLs like APL\1130 didn't have the suffix vector function (see page 208 of [here](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Manuals/APL1130Primer)).

Answer (score 8):

## Forth,  1970 + 38 = 2008

```
:s tuck +do 0 . loop 0 +do -1 . loop ;
```

usage:  `7 3 s` prints "0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1"

Comment: Now we're talking!

Comment: Why -1? filler+

Comment: That's one of the more interesting 'truthy' values I've seen lately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23832703/10396

Comment: Is there a good reason this is named `sv` and not `s`, or something else one byte?

Comment: Good question;  changed.

Comment: What's `+do` do?

Comment: Pops `i`, then `j` from the stack and does the equivalent of `for (;i<j;i++) ` on the following instructions up to  `loop`

Answer (score 8):

## SAS, 1966 + 45 = 2011

```
data;a=;b=;do i=1to a;c=a-i<b;put c@;end;run;
```

Time for SAS to shine!

SAS wasn't first published until 1972, but this data step only uses very basic features that I'm fairly confident would have been available even in the earliest pre-release versions from 1966 onwards, so I believe it would have worked then. Input goes after `a=` and `b=`, and output is printed to the log.

I would be amazed if anyone still had an [IBM System/360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360) with the right version of SAS to actually verify this!

Comment: [The machine is available.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_(emulator)#Operating_systems_statushttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_(emulator)#Operating_systems_status)...

Comment: Now, if only I had the cash for a [mainframe SAS licence](http://www.execinfosys.com/ProductsOld/IBMMF_2.pdf)...

Answer (score 8):

### APL, 1968+5=1973

Down to 5 chars:

```
⌽⎕≥⍳⎕
```

---

Older version:

```
⌽⎕↑⎕⍴1
```

Well, you actually already gave the answer, i just removed the dynamic function definition and checked that this one worked in 1968. For reference here is the manual:

http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Books/APL360ReferenceManual

Comment: Kids, this is called a _winner_. Please write that down in your notes.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Not yet. @​Moris Zucca: Finally, but you can actually golf half of those bytes away. Can you figure out how? Also, [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APL360TerminalSystem.htm) is a much more modern and readable version of the manual.

Answer (score 5):

## [Mouse-1979](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse79/index.html), 1979 + 19 = 1998

```
??&TUCK (0.a)0(1-.)
```

Translation of: [Forth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75307/46231).

The spec is really cryptic to me but I think this does the right thing.

Comment: Broken link....

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Fixed; I typed it from memory.

Comment: Interesting. But I don't think the `&Tuck` was available until the 2002 version. And the loops appear to be infinite.

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 1990 + 21 = 2011

The first TI calculator that this program works on is the TI-81, introduced in 1990.

```
Prompt A,B:"{}
seq(I>A-B,I,1,A
```

**Edit:** noticed that I must support an empty list... increased code by 4 bytes

## Test Cases

```
A=?7
B=?3
{0 0 0 0 1 1 1}

A=?4
B=?4
{1 1 1 1}

A=?2
B=?0
{0 0}

A=?0
B=?0
{}   * throws an error but still returns successfully
```

Comment: Could you add commentary on which parts of the source are single bytes in TI-Basic? I think that includes Prompt and seq( but I'm not sure about the rest

Comment: We don't consider returning through `Ans` an acceptable output method, unless it's printed.

Comment: @Sparr Sure, `Prompt` and `seq(` are one byte tokens and the other characters are one byte each.

Comment: @lirtosiast `Ans` is the default way to return a value in the TI-83 series Basic. Additionally, when a program is run, the last line is printed automatically. So you have the best of both worlds.

Comment: When the list is empty, though, Ans contains the string `{}`. Even if we say that's a representation of an empty list, it's never printed. As for Ans being the default return variable, you should ask on meta.

Comment: @lirtosiast True, for the last case it is not explicitly displayed, but it is still returned. There is no other way to return a value except for `Ans`.

Comment: In general we do not allow programs or functions to output values by storing them into variables, but we do allow them to print. If you think an exception should be made for `Ans`, please post on meta.

Comment: Too bad this has to support empty list...then it would be winning (by 1 yearbyte)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I know...

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy NOt at all, I have a solution in mind that *scores* 1970.

Comment: Is it the Analytical Engine? Somebody should do that...

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 1.0, 1988+22 bytes=2010

```
Array[#>m&/.m->#-#2,#]&
```

I'm not sure if this works, just went through the documentation on 10.3 and looked for things that said *Introduced in 1988 (1.0)*

Comment: _Just about_ the current winner. If only the SMP code could get shorter...

Comment: On another note though, some docs: [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/4.1.4.pdf), [`/.` and `->`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/B.2.2.pdf), [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/1.7.3.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

## 68k TI-Basic, 1995 + 25 = 2020

The first TI calculator that this program works on is the TI-92, introduced in 1995.

```
define f(a,b)=seq(x>a-b,x,1,a)
```

Unlike the TI-83 series, 68k TI-Basic supports the empty list.

Comment: How is the size counted? Tokenization is very different on the 68k series.

Comment: Prompt and seq are both two bytes plus a one byte flag for multiple arguments. (21 bytes)

Comment: Note that this is neither a program nor a function in the context of the 68k calculators: `Prompt` is invalid in a function, and a program can't return a value. So this has to be entered on the home screen. On the other hand, `define f(a,b)=seq(x>a-b,x,1,a)` does define a valid function that can be given a and b as arguments. (Verified on my TI-92 from 1995-09-13)

Comment: I own several TI calculators (the only z80-version being the 81), but usually use a TI-92 Plus. After running this `define` and calling `f(2,1)` or similar to tokenize it, the size reported by the OS is 25 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 1.0, 1994 + 26 = 2020

Saved 2 bytes thanks to DSM.

Lambda was introduced with the first major release, 1.0

```
lambda a,b:[0]*(a-b)+[1]*b
```

Comment: Confirmed [lambda introduced in 1.0, list (sequence) repetition in 0.9.2](http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/trunk/Misc/HISTORY). The oldest version I could test this on (apart from 0.9.1) was [1.5.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/), and it works fine there.

Comment: @Sp3000 Oh wow, that's awesome. I've been trying to find some change logs to confirm that the sequence repetition was in the language that early.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 2015 + 1 + 4 = 2020

```
:P<~
```

This works since [release 6.0.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/6.0.0) of the language (it uses implicit input, which was introduced in that release), dated December 31, 2015.

I've added `1` to the score in accordance with @drolex comment on possibly different locales.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OlA8fg&input=Nwoz)

#### Explanation

```
:    % take first input implicitly. Generate inclusive range from 1 to that
P    % flip that array
<~   % take second input implicitly. True for elements of flipped array that
     % exceed second number. Display implicitly
```

Comment: One day later, and...

Comment: Objection! We'll need to have the locales for the github server and the release submitter. If one is in Tonga and the other in Hawaii, this count might need to be incremented.

Comment: @drolex The OP should define what he means by "year", exactly. Meantime, I'm adding 1 to my score

Comment: @DonMuesli I didn't mean it, just showing the potential limitations of this type of scoring

Comment: @drolex Oh, I thought you were serious. I've asked the OP, anyway. Github date should probably count as official

Answer (score 3):

## J, 1990 + 8 = 1998

```
|.a{.b#1
```

Argh. Was researching this answer and someone got to APL before I could hope to understand the language. Here's my J solution instead.

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog, 1972 + 57 = 2029

```
a(0,_,[]).
a(A,B,[H|L]):-Z is A-1,a(Z,B,L),(Z<B,H=1;H=0).
```

**Usage:** `a(7,3,L).` will unify `L` with `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1]`.

I'm really not quite sure when `is` was implemented in the language, and I doubt you can actually find the exact date. It's a pretty basic built-in though so I assume it was already existing when the language first appeared in [1972](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog).

Not that it really matters though, I'm far from winning with this answer.

Comment: This may not be the winner, but it clearly illustrates the advantage of exploring - ehm - mature languages...

Answer (score 2):

## [SMP](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/smp-symbolic-manipulation-program/smp-reference-manual.pdf), 1983+28 bytes=2011

```
Map[S[$1>x,x->$1-$2],Ar[$1]]
```

I think I got this right...
`S`:2.10, page 48
`Ar`:7.1, page 102
`Map`:7.2, page 106
`$1`:7.1, page 104

And if you're familiar with Mathematica, no, `Ar` doesn't work like *that*. More like `Range`+`Select`.

Comment: `(#>x&/.x->#)/@Range[#+#2]&` in Mathematica

Comment: I mean `(#>x&/.x->#-#2)/@Range[#]&`

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 1991 + 21 = 2012

```
"adwj<c-x>"bdw@ai0<esc>v@bhr1
```

Input looks like this:

```
7
3
```

And output looks like this:

```
0000111
```

Explanation:

```
"adw                            'Delete a word into register a
    j<c-x>                      'Go down a line, and decrement the next number to occur
          "bdw                  'Delete a word into register b
              @ai0<esc>         'Insert a '0' "a" times
                       v        'Enter visual mode
                        @bh     'Move "b" characters left
                           r1   'Replace the whole selection with the character '1'
```

Comment: Too bad vi doesn't support registers, because it was released in 1976!

Comment: Explanation please?

Answer (score 2):

## [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%28programming_language%29), 1971 + 54 = 2025

```
s(l,t){while(t<l--)printn(0,8);while(t--)printn(1,8);}
```

See "[The User's Reference to B](https://web.archive.org/web/20150611114427/https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/kbman.pdf)" for the manual for this typeless C precursor.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 2015 + <s>9</s> 4 = <s>2024</s> 2019

Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for his help!

```
gRQE
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=gRQE&input=3%0A7&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A7%0A4%0A4%0A0%0A2%0A0%0A0&debug=0&input_size=2)

### Explanation

```
gRQE    # Q = amount of trailing truthy values
        # E = length of the vector
 R E    # map over range(E)
g Q     # d >= Q
```

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 2009 + 14 + 3 for -v = 2026

`b` and `a` should be provided directly on the stack with `-v`, in reverse order.

The output isn't space separated as in the examples, but that does not seem to go against any stated rule. It uses 0 and 1 to represent false and true, as used by the language.

```
:?!;{:0(n1-}1-
```

It doesn't work with the current version since `?` now pops its test value from the stack.

I'm not confident every feature was implemented from day 1, `-v` for example could have been provided later as a commodity. I'll try to make sure my answer is correct this weekend.

Comment: ? didn't pop (a long time ago) as stated in the quine challenge

Comment: Thanks, that's great news, I'll save 1 byte :) I'll edit that now, but I'll have to check the resources linked on esolang.org, some date back to at least 2011.

Comment: [Quine challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/2148#2148) and [esolang](https://esolangs.org/w/index.php?title=Fish&oldid=22141#Instructions)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wouldn't have thought to check the wiki's revisions ! I'm currently at work and won't probably be able to check everything yet, but I'll make sure to do it this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: Score=2026 now.

Comment: Woops, thanks. Although I think I'll have to put 2010, that's the oldest documented version on the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2016 + 9 = 2025

This can definitely be golfed further, but here's a start :p. Code:

```
-0s×1¹×«S
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LTBzw5cxwrnDl8KrUw&input=Mwo3) The input is given as *b, a*.

Also 9 bytes: [`0×1I×0ñRS`](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MMOXMUnDlzDDsVJT&input=Nwoz).

Comment: [Yeah, it can definitely be golfed...](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f99CGQ8sMD@08PP3Q6uD//425zAE) (did `°` exist back in 2016 btw?)

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v1, [2006](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/11/14/its-a-wrap-windows-powershell-1-0-released/) + 28 = 2034

```
param($a,$b),0*($a-$b)+,1*$b
```

Uses the [comma operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell/) to construct the array(s), which has been in PowerShell since the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathcad, 1998 + 42 = 2040

"bytes" are interpreted as number of distinct keyboard characters (eg, 'for' operator (including one programming line) is a single character ctl-shft-#, or a click on the Programming toolbar)).

The above byte count assumes that the a and b definitions don't count towards the total; add 4 bytes for definitions if this assumption is invalid.

The function version shown below adds 5 bytes for the definition and a further 3 bytes for each use (assuming the a and b values are directly typed in).

As my Mathcad solution should clearly be playing off the red tees and not the competition ones, I've added a table of solutions.  Note that as Mathcad has no empty array, I've used an empty string ("") instead; I've used 0 to indicate where I haven't calculated the b>a pairs.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)) ([kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona)), 1993 + 15 = 2008

```
((a-b)#0b),b#1b
```

Creates list of b True values, and concatenates it to a list of (a-b) False values.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 1995 + 56 bytes = 2051

```
function s($a,$b){while($i++<$a)$v[]=$i>$a-$b;return$v;}
```

**Exploded view**

```
function s($a,$b) {
  while ($i++ < $a) $v[] = $i > $a - $b;
  return $v;
}
```

Comment: Uh..there's custom scoring. It's _first year language woks in+byte count_.

Comment: Whoops, right you are!  Fixing...

Comment: Making the probably-incorrect assumption of this working in PHP 1.  Will verify version soon.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 2015 + 46 = 2061

Returns array of 0 and 1

```
(a,b)=>Array(a-b).fill(0).concat(Array(b).fill(1))
```

## Javascript ES6, 2015 + 50 = 2065

Returns a string of `0` and `1` chars

```
(a,b)=>Array(a-b+1).join(0)+Array(b+1).join(1)
```

## Javascript, 1995 + 61 = 2056

Returns a string of `0` and `1` chars

```
function(a,b){return Array(a-b+1).join(0)+Array(b+1).join(1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes + 1993 = 2013

```r
function(a,b)1:a>a-b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJ09Aq0S5RN@l/moaZjpHmfwA)

Possibly this might work in S, which would drop the score to 2008, but I haven't been able to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC 3, 2014 + 25 = 2039

The first publicly available version of SmileBASIC 3 launched in Japan with the SmileBASIC app for Nintendo 3DS in November 2014.

Prints a string where 0 is false and 1 is true (as they are in the language itself.)

```
INPUT A,B?"0"*(A-B)+"1"*B
```